# getting Error while send data to game centre

Tags: iphone, ios6, game-center, xcode4.6

I  getting  crash while  send NSData to Game Center in Xcode.
here is the scree shot.
hope a good solution for my issue thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you are dividing by zero, either your currentmatch.participants is blank or nil.